# Microsoft Access Date Function

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to create a query on a table that filters out dates.  I need to display all records previous to a specific date, but need this to be dynamically updated annually.

Specifically, I need to find dates prior to October 1 of the previous year.  (i.e. anything prior to Oct 1, 2012.) 
I know I can use '<#10/1/2012#' but would like to make this dynamic to update every year, as this same function will be utilized for multiple queries.

I have tried several iterations of the Date() function to get this to work, to no avail.
Things that don't work are...

Year([TrainingDate])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[TrainingDate] < DateSerial(Year(Date())-1,10,1)
```

`Date()` is the current date, so `Year(Date())` is the current year.